# Spring Boot Basic Auth for each request, username validated for later requests

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I have enabled the http basic auth in spring boot. I am seeing strange results when calling from Postman

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private ApiUserDetailsService userDetails;

  @Bean
  public ShaPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new ShaPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    ReflectionSaltSource salt = new ReflectionSaltSource();
    salt.setUserPropertyToUse("username");
    DaoAuthenticationProvider dao = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    dao.setUserDetailsService(userDetails);
    dao.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    dao.setSaltSource(salt);
    auth.authenticationProvider(dao);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable().httpBasic();
  }
```

Custome Userdetails

```
@Service
public class ApiUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Value("${spring.queries.users.query}")
  private String usersQuery;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    List<UserDetails> usersBasedOnUserName = getUsersBasedOnUserName(username);

    if (usersBasedOnUserName.size() == 0) {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username " + username + " not found");
    }
    return usersBasedOnUserName.get(0);
  }

  private List<UserDetails> getUsersBasedOnUserName(String username) {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(this.usersQuery, new String[] {username}, new RowMapper<UserDetails>() {
      @Override
      public UserDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        String username = rs.getString(1);
        String password = rs.getString(2);
        return new User(username, password, AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

For the fist time I execute the request, it expects the correct credentials. After I enter correct credentials, I get the result. But when I try for the the same request without credentials or diffrent password keepign username same, I wont get 401 error.

I will get 401 error only when I chnage username.

My API needs to be validated against each request.

Am I doing some thing wrong here.

Comment: Can you post the code for DaoAuthenticationProvider?

Answer (score 5):

Adding the stateless to config helped to solve issue.

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
   http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable().httpBasic(); 
  }
```